# Java: Uncanny behaviour of for-loop with composite condition

Tags: java, for-loop

I've been developing a prime decomposition code in java. For such, I have, at a certain point, a code similar to this:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 40 && isPrime(i); ++i){
    System.out.println(i + " is less or equal to 40 and prime.");
}
```

This code, however, has a rather uncanny behaviour because it only tests for `i=2` and `i=3`. There's nothing wrong with the `isPrime()` method. To thicken the plot, the following code works fine:

```
for(int i = 4; i <= 40; ++i){
    if(isPrime(i))
        System.out.println(i + " is less or equal to 40 and prime.");
}
```

This might be a very stupid question but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a for-loop, the condition decides whether to *continue or terminate* the loop.

Therefore, once `(i<= 40 && isPrime(i))` evaluates to *false* for the first time in your program execution, the loop is no longer run. This happens at the first composite, 4. Thus, only 2 and 3 are written to screen.

Comment: Indeed this was a dumb question... Thank you for your patience, anyway ^^

Comment: @PML It's not really a dumb question, as someone else is apt to come across this issue and might find this question by googling.

Answer (score 3):

The second expression in `for` loop states "stop looping if this evaluates to false". Using `while` loop, the

```
for(A;B;C) {
    D;
}
```

loop could be rewritten to

```
A;
while (B) {
    D;
    C;
}
```

So as soon as you process a composite number, the loop terminates. Which is 4 in your case.

Answer (score 1):

For loops are quite interesting in the repetition part of Java. The for loop works in a way of:

- Variable Assignment (VA)
- Condition to keep running (Cdnl)
- Incrementation (Inc)

To fix the problem in the code you need to understand where the problem is first. Typical for new beginners to Java, one might think that if the Cdnl (Conditional) is false, then it will continue to the next number. Wrong, if the Cdnl is false, the loop will break. For loops can be seen as a quicker while loop:

```
int i = 0;
while(i <= 10) {
  System.out.println(i);
  i++;
}
//This is equal to:
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Enough jamble, let's fix the code. The problem is with your conditional. Easy fix:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 40; i++) {
  if(!isPrime(i)) continue;
  System.out.println(i + " is less or equal to 40 and prime.");
}
```

`if(!isPrime(i)) continue;` just means that if *i* is **NOT** prime, then it will skip to the end of the loop, thus incrementing and attempting the next number. Do not be fooled by thinking `continue;` means to continue code execution. Simple rookie blunder.

Hope this fixes it.

Jarod.